# DRY way to handle users with multiple accounts in Rails app

Tags: ruby, activerecord, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activemodel

This is a Rails app for a school. I'm using Devise for user accounts. So far each user has a `.role` of `admin`, `teacher` or `student` which restricts what the user can access and contribute in the app. I'm using `user.email` to log in. All is working great so far.

Now I've realized that I have a problem with sibling accounts. The unique `user.email` used for logging in is actually the parent's email address (since the students are minors) and now I have to account for a parent with two or more children who are students. I obviously can't have a `student` account for each child and use the same email address because it has to be unique (and I do want to keep the requirement in the validation).

Given that I already have a large chuck of the app done, what would be a nice DRY way to account for this situation?

I've searched this site and others but not really found anything that accounts for this situation.

One way I thought would be to change the role in the `User` model to parent and then have a separate `Student` model . A user with the role of parent could then `has_many :students` but this doesn't sit well with me.

Any general ideas/concepts would be appreciated, as would any pointers to articles or gems that would help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best way, but one approach would be to append a sibling-unique identifier to the name portion of the parent's email address for all student email addresses. You could do it in such a way that it could be stripped off when you wanted the "real" email address. There's actually some precedent for this kind of approach, per http://www.plankdesign.com/blog/2013/06/testing-infinite-unique-email-addresses-with-gmail/.

Comment: That's interesting. It would certainly be easy to implement without much disruption to my models but I'm not sure it would be very user-friendly. I'll give it a go on a branch and see how it feels.

Comment: You wouldn't have to do this for the first child of any given parent, only the second and beyond, at the cost of some additional code for email generation.

Comment: Are you suggesting parents have 2 different sets of log in credentials and log into 2 separate accounts? Ideally I'd like a parent to log in and see details for all of their children in one dashboard. I've been advised this will affect about 10% of parents.

Comment: I actually had assumed that you wanted separate accounts for each student. If you just want one account, then it seems to me that you're really talking about a *parent* account and student is a separate abstraction.

Comment: I think you're right. I need to forget the idea of getting this to work within my current models and look at a separate Student account. Thanks.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer above because it does answer my question, but since my question was malformed it doesn't actually solve my problem! :)